# efeito barra enchendo css no menu

Tags: css, menu, style

gente preciso recriar o efeito do menu desse site: http://mpcaminhoes.com.br/ 
porém não estou conseguindo, consegui criar a barra e fazer a barra crescer mas ela cresce por cima do menu, tampando o escrito....... da maneira que eu tentei é fazendo uma classe com 0 de largura depois no hover pegar largura total e adicionar o transition, tentei fazer com o proprio background do menu mas não funciona porque como originalmente precisa ter 0 de largura, entao o menu fica sem largura inicial..... sou iniciante, alguem consegue me ajudar? segue o codigo css

```
.hover-menu:after{
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
 left:0%;
 width:0;
 height:50px;
 background:#fb3c03;
 display:block;
 content:"";
 transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hover-menu:hover:after{
 width:100%;
}
```

Eu peguei esse codigo de um projeto e ele usa o content vazio... se eu retirar esse content vazio não funciona.. no css a classe hover menu esta no meu "a"

Comment: corrigindo no html a classe hover menu esta no meu "a"

Comment: Coloca o teu html também, André

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que setar `z-index: -1` no `::after` e `z-index: 1` no elemento. Exemplo:

```css
body{
   background: #ddd;
}

ul, li{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

li{
   list-style: none;
   padding: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   background: #777;
   line-height: 1em;
   margin: 0 5px;
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #fff;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}

li::after{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 0;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: orange;
   z-index: -1;
   transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover::after{
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Menu 1</li>
   <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar `z-index:-1` no `::after` ai ele aparece por traz do texto.

**OBS:** *coloquei na transição um efeito igual ao do site com `cubic-bezier`, deixei comentado tb no css, agora a animação está igual ao do site de exemplo.*

Veja o exemplo. *(deixei o comment no código)*

```css
.hover-menu:after{
 position: absolute;
 top:0px;
 border-radius: 0 15px 0 0;
 left:0%;
 width:0;
 height:50px;
 background:#fb3c03;
 display:block;
 content:"";
 transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.52,1.64,.37,.66); /*animação para ficar igual a do site do exemplo */
 z-index: -1;  /* coloque z-index aqui */
}
.hover-menu:hover:after{
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hover-menu">link</a>
```